# What do you call widely-pursued but exclusive careers where people are high-paid? (Superstars)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm interested in finding writings on the subject of pursuing, "Superstar" or "wildest dreams" careers, but all my searches kept yielding writings about common careers and workplace settings that are merely described in superlative terms.

Please help me find a word or phrase that describes the most aspirational and exclusive of careers, such as famous musician, actor, influencer, creator, professional athlete, supermodel or other such careers to which many may aspire, but only a tiny fraction will achieve. As it's inherently somewhat subjective, please don't get lost in trying to define exactly which careers fit this definition.

The term should capture the make-or-break essence, in which the majority who don't achieve the high threshold for success will have to change careers. This is in contrast to something like a company executive, where most unsuccessful aspirants can comfortably remain on the business professional career path.

Comment: Are you looking for search terms that will bring up writings on the subject? Or are you looking for a word or words that you can use in a sentence?

Comment: If the latter, can you add a fill-in-the-blank _____ example sentence?

Comment: Do you want an adjective or a noun? Either can be said to "describe" something.  I see that Heartspring has assumed you want adjectives. I had assumed nouns.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I would appreciate having both nouns and adjectives which describe such careers.

Comment: pipe dream careers

Answer (score 1):

You used the word *aspirational,* which works pretty well.

> of, relating to, or characterized by aspiration... associated with or suggestive of a high level of success and social status and therefore appealing to people who aspire to such status ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspirational))

Also useful could be *high-reaching*, which is defined by [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/High-reaching) as

> Reaching high or upward; hence, ambitious; aspiring.

Also, consider *ambitious*:

> If a plan or idea is ambitious, it needs a great amount of skill and effort to be successful or be achieved ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ambitious))

And *glamorous* turns up many results online that are related to what you're looking for, although most definitions don't include this aspect:

> attractive in an exciting and special way [Ex] *a glamorous job* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glamorous))

Less specifically these are *competitive* careers:

> relating to, characterized by, or based on competition ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competitive))

These are also known as *win-or-bust* careers, in addition to *make-or-break*, which you mentioned:

> [of a plan] that will either completely succeed or completely fail ([Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/win-or-bust.html#:%7E:text=Adjective,completely%20succeed%20or%20completely%20fail))

Answer (score 1):

**high-flyer (flier)**

> highflier
>
> noun US (UK high-flyer, high-flier, highflyer) someone who
> has a lot of ability and a strong wish to be successful and is
> therefore expected to achieve a lot: Highfliers in the industry
> typically earn 25 percent more than their colleagues.
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highflier

**the elite**

> elite
>
> noun [ C, + sing/pl verb ] UK  /iˈliːt/ US  /iˈliːt/
> the richest, most powerful, best-educated, or best-trained group in a
> society: the country's educated elite a member of the elite
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elite